# Issue building rust docs in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, doc, substrate

### Overview

I am having an issue building rust documentation with GitHub Actions for a particular repo. The repo is open-source and you can view it [here](https://github.com/dutterbutter/protocol-substrate) and the erroring GitHub Action [here](https://github.com/dutterbutter/protocol-substrate/runs/7027487414?check_suite_focus=true). The linked repo is a fork but it also fails with the same error on the upstream repo. You can also view the current GitHub Action workflow file [here](https://github.com/dutterbutter/protocol-substrate/actions/runs/2550454607/workflow).

Running `cargo doc --release --no-deps --open` locally works perfectly fine, but in the CI environment it fails with the below message.

#### Things I've tried

- Excluding the problematic packages using `--exclude`, but in doing so, the next package complains (e.g. first it was `webb-client`, then `webb-primitives`)
- Fetching the submodules before running cargo doc
- Running `cargo build --release` before running cargo doc
- Running with `all-features` flag

#### Some relevant issues I found

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93698

#### Error from CI

```
thread 'rustc' panicked at 'no entry found for key', src/librustdoc/passes/collect_intra_doc_links.rs:930:16
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: internal compiler error: unexpected panic
error: Unrecognized option: 'crate-version'
error: could not document `webb-primitives`
```

Comment: You're encountering a bug in rustdoc (the tool that `cargo doc` runs). However, you seem to be using an old version (`rustc 1.60.0-nightly (498eeb72f 2022-01-31)`) in CI. Try updating to a newer nightly (e.g., 2022-06-22) by changing your `rust-toolchain.toml` file. I suspect you may be using a newer version locally, which is why you can't reproduce the bug. If you still get the panic on a new nightly, open an issue at http://github.com/rust-lang/rust.

Comment: Thank you! I overlooked the `rust-toolchain.toml`, once I updated the problem was solved!